# How to get linked panoId for google Photo Sphere?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view, photosphere

I'm having hard time to find linked `panoId` form a given `Photo Sphere` panoid.

If it is a `google` `see insides` i am getting the linked panoId by using this API

http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=xml&panoid=<`PANO ID`>

But in case of `Photo Sphere` this API is not returning the XML data. Can any one help me out with this problem.

`see insides` Pano ID = "enEZO0FuPFAAAAQvxYdP0w"

`Photo Sphere` Pano ID = "F:-fr8FidB2CSQ/V49sgVq8pHI/AAAAAAAABFw/bMktS2vh6mcQtQB6y1-vBXTPTZCCnxTbQCLIB"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL `http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=xml&panoid=<PANO ID>` is not documented feature, you should be aware that Google Maps API Terms of Service prohibits to access imagery using undocumented channels. See paragraph 10.1(a) of ToS:

> **No access to APIs or Content except through the Service.** You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1

To access panorama data via service you should use API. For example, in Maps JavaScript API you can use StreetViewService class.

**Code snippet**

```js
var panorama;
      function initialize() {
          var svService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
          var panoRequest = {
              pano: "F:-fr8FidB2CSQ/V49sgVq8pHI/AAAAAAAABFw/bMktS2vh6mcQtQB6y1-vBXTPTZCCnxTbQCLIB"
          };
        
          svService.getPanorama(panoRequest, function(panoData, status){
              if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
                  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
                      document.getElementById('street-view'),
                      {
                          pano: panoData.location.pano,
                          pov: {
                              heading: 10,
                              pitch: 10
                          }
                      });
                   console.log(panoData);
              } else {
                  //Handle other statuses here
              }
          });
      }
```

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
#street-view {
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="street-view"></div>
<script async defer
         src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initialize">
    </script>
```

Exists also [Street View Image Metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) web service, but currently it doesn't work with Photo Spheres.

There is a bug in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35831151

However, Google didn't expose any ETA on when or if it might be fixed. You can star the public issue to add your vote.

**UPDATE**

Recently, Google enabled access to PhotoSpheres via Street View Image API. Although, the pano ID format has changed.

The `F:-fr8FidB2CSQ/V49sgVq8pHI/AAAAAAAABFw/bMktS2vh6mcQtQB6y1-vBXTPTZCCnxTbQCLIB` is now `CAMSSi1mcjhGaWRCMkNTUS9WNDlzZ1ZxOHBISS9BQUFBQUFBQUJGdy9iTWt0UzJ2aDZtY1F0UUI2eTEtdkJYVFBUWkNDbnhUYlFDTElC`

Please look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43426922/5140781) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the information about No access to APIs @xomena. It has given me all the required data what I want. It's works great with both the cases for   `Photo Sphere` as well as `See Insides`